# Does PyPy work with Py2Exe?

Tags: python, py2exe, pypy

Does [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) work with [Py2Exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)? If it doesn't, are there any similar solutions?

Comment: I'm trying to see if an application I made using pypy will work with py2exe to create a pseudo-executable/Whatever you want to call it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no (would be possible to get it running, but hard)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the answer is "no". py2exe appears to depend on CPython's C API, which I'm pretty sure PyPy doesn't support. (That is, I can't see why PyPy would support the CPython API, nor did I see any mention it in any of the obvious places on their website...)

Comment: PyPy is trying to fully implement the CPython api.  It isn't fully compatible but they have several C modules working.

Comment: I hope they mention it on their website now?